# Finding % of rows in a table that exist in another table?

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following tables:

```
Table A:

entryDate              memberID           course
```

Each memberID can occur multiple times during the same date

```
2016-05-10      1192875         STAT-2294

2016-05-10      3292875         STAT-2294

2016-05-10      1192875         ENG-115
```

Table B consists only of memberIDs

What I’m looking for is a way to find the % of memberIDs in Table A that exist in Table B on a given day.

This is where I'm at so far:

```
SELECT entryDate, 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN tableA.memberID IN (SELECT memberID 
                                        FROM   tableB) THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END) AS membership 
FROM   tableA 
WHERE  entryDate BETWEEN ‘2016-05-01’ AND ‘2016-05-15’ 
GROUP  BY entryDate;
```

I'm trying to get the raw count as a starting point but I get the following error

> Unsupported SubQuery Expression ‘memberID': Currently SubQuery
>   expressions are only allowed as Where Clause predicates

- What is wrong with my current query?
- How can I get the % of rows in TableA that exist in TableB for a specific entryDate?

TIA! -Craig

Comment: Although I agree with the answer below, a direct response to your *Error Message* is that you're missing some brackets.  Sub-queries need brackets, and so does the IN statement, which then gives the following code block `IN ( (SELECT blah FROM blah) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `exists` to do this.

```
select count(*) 
from tableA a
where exists (select 1 from tableB b where a.memberID = b.memberID)
and entryDate BETWEEN '20160501' AND '20160515'
```

To get the % entries,

```
select 100.0 * count(*) / (select count(*) 
                           from tableA a
                           where exists (select 1 from tableB b where a.memberID = b.memberID)
                           and entryDate BETWEEN '20160501' AND '20160515')
from tableA 
where entryDate BETWEEN '20160501' AND '20160515'
```

Edit: Correlated subqueries aren't supported in Hive, this can be done with a `left join`.

```
select 100.0 * count(b.memberID) / count(a.memberID)
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.memberID = b.memberID and a.entryDate BETWEEN '20160501' AND '20160515'
```

Comment: Thanks @vkp, I get this error for the % query: ParseException line 1:27 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count' '(' in expression specification - any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the error message you get is because correlated sub-queries aren't supported in Hive. I will edit the answer to use a `left join`.

Answer (score 4):

I think `LEFT JOIN` is the easiest method.  Assuming `tableB` has no duplicates:

```
SELECT entryDate, COUNT(*) as numA,
       COUNT(b.memberId) as numB,
       AVG(CASE WHEN b.memberId is not null THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) as ratio
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.memberId = b.memberId
WHERE entryDate BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-15' 
GROUP BY entryDate;
```